# Fullscreen games are showing title bar

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, 20.10, fullscreen, titlebar

A few days ago, most fullscreen games launched via Steam began showing the title bar no matter what settings I have configured. I am not sure what would have changed to cause this to start happening. It seems that games running with proton work as expected, but games with native linux clients show the title bar.
[Screenshot of example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R14r7.jpg)

I am running a 3 monitor set up (left=1920x1080, center=3840x2160, right=3840x2160) running with a GeForce RTX 2070 Super on the Nvidia v455 drivers.

```
:~$ xrander

Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 9600 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+451 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1440x480      59.94  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.93    59.94  
DP-2 connected primary 3840x2160+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  30.00  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 connected 3840x2160+5760+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  30.00  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
USB-C-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

As mentioned, a few days ago I was able to run games full screen as expected.
Things I've tried:

- Downgrading the nvidia drivers to version 450
- Launching with the '-fullscreen' launch option
- Setting nvidia_drm modeset=1
- Forcing Composition Pipeline
- Enabling 'auto-hide dock' as suggested by RingGamesCompany

I am out of ideas. If anyone with more experience than I has any ideas, or if there's any additional information I can supply, I'm happy to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to solve this issue, thanks to a post on the /r/pop_os subreddit, I found the following issue that was logged with Valve: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/csgo-osx-linux/issues/2551

Based on this, it is a bug in the currently deployed version of mutter in the Ubuntu repository. The issue is found here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1486

I downgraded the `libmutter-7-0` and `gir1.2-mutter-7` packages to the previous version via `apt install libmutter-7-0=3.38.1-1ubuntu1 gir1.2-mutter-7=3.38.1-1ubuntu1`

Games are now displaying in fullscreen as expected. I'll await the fixed mutter packages in the repo before upgrading again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, what you do is go to settings > appareance > auto hide Dock

This should work ( i just did it because i re-installed ubuntu)
But if this doesn't work... Try surfing the internet to get some better results

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve the issue. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @Adam I might be able to find a way but.... I remember i did it. Oh, maybe try 'set resolution'. My bar isn't showing when im playing war thunder.... Try set resolution to 'auto or find out what your pixels are e.g 1080x780, that might help. Then set your resolution  to your screen size.